# VC++ MFC -> ComboBox, GetCurSel()?

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, mfc

Where am I going wrong? I have this code:

```
CComboBox m_item;

if((m_item.GetCurSel()) == atoi("TC001"))
    MessageBox(L"TC001");

if((m_item.GetCurSel()) == atoi("TC002"))
    MessageBox(L"TC002");
```

If I select "TC001" in the `ComboxBox`, it pops up **both** "TC001" and "TC002" message boxes.

If I select "TC002" in the `ComboxBox`, it doesn't show **any** `MessageBox`.

Why?

Comment: `atoi` [converts a `string` to an `int`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/), if that is possible. `TC001` is not a valid `int`, therefore I think this could be the issue.

Comment: Have you checked what `atoi("TC001")` returns? I bet you will be surprised.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi):

> Interprets an integer value in a byte string pointed to by str.
>
> Discards any whitespace characters until the first non-whitespace character is found, then takes as many characters as possible to form a valid integer number representation and converts them to an integer value. The valid integer value consists of the following parts:
>
> - (optional) plus or minus sign
> - numeric digits
>
> [...] If no conversion can be performed, ​`0`​ is returned.

The strings `"TC001"` and `"TC002"` cannot be converted to an integer, thus the call to `atoi` returns `0` in both cases.

[CComboBox::GetCurSel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#getcursel) returns

> the zero-based index of the currently selected item in the list box of a combo box [...]

Thus, if the item with display string `"TC001"` is the first item, `GetCurSel` returns `0`, the same value returned by `atoi` on non-integer input. Both comparisons return `true`, so both message boxes are shown.

The solution is two-fold:

- Learn how to use a debugger.
- Don't use string comparisons or conversions to determine the selected value. Instead use the positional index, or attach custom data to each item. This requires either calling [CComboBox::SetItemData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#setitemdata), or switching to a [CComboBoxEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccomboboxex-class) class that provides the [InsertItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccomboboxex-class#insertitem) member, so you can pass a [COMBOBOXITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb775746) structure and use its `lParam` member.

Comment: Okay,
But, can you please demo me with an example?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @user9374422: Since you never explained what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, it is not possible for me to show you, how to do that. Your question asks, why your proposed solution to an undisclosed issue doesn't exhibit the expected result, and I answered that question. If you have a new question, hit the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Okay, I'll tell you my issue in detail,
I have a Combo box in my MFC VC++ Application. There are 4 strings which I added in the ComboBox.
Now, say if i have selected the 2nd string in the comboBox, it should do some task. I'm not able to get the selected item through GetSelCur(). Can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: @user9374422: So then, write `if (m_item.GetCurSel() == 1) { /* Do something */ }`. Anyway, this question has been answered. If you have a new question, you know what to do. In the meantime, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You can also use `SetItemData` or `SetItemDataPtr`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ekb53ey.aspx

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: That's true, thanks. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to compare the selected text, and not the selected item number. To do that use [`CComboBox::GetLBText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcy9kze7(v=vs.120).aspx).

```
CStringW text;
m_item.GetLBText(m_item.GetCurSel(), text);

if (text == L"TC001")
    MessageBox(L"TC001");
else if (text == L"TC002")
    MessageBox(L"TC002");
```

Comment: `CString` and wide character string literals are incompatible. Either use `CStringW`, or wrap the string literals in `_T()` macros. The latter is not recommended.

Comment: @IInspectable I thought the wide-char prefix `L` would cause this operator to be called: `BOOL operator ==( const CString& s1, LPCTSTR s2 );` [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315046(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: It causes either [`friend bool operator==(const CStringT& str1, PCXSTR psz2)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#operator_eq_eq) or `friend bool operator==(const CStringT& str1, PCYSTR psz2)` to get called. The latter performs a conversion, that is likely unwanted, and usually the cause for very subtle bugs.

Comment: I always use the _T macro. I never use L.